# How can I detect a crash between two objects on the canvas accounting for rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using Javascript and HTML to make a 2D web game using the canvas tag. I currently have a ground and a ship. My struggle is coming from detecting collisions between the two. It would be as simple as seeing if any of the edges overlap, like what is done in the W3Schools example shown in the link at the bottom. My problem is that my ship can rotate, and the collision code doesn't account for such. I have included the code for detecting collisions, and in case its helpful the code for drawing the ship (and rotated).

Collision Code:

```js
        this.crashWith = function (otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
                (mytop > otherbottom) ||
                (myright < otherleft) ||
                (myleft > otherright)) {
                crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
        };
```

Ship Drawing Code:

```js
        this.update = function () {
            var ctx = gameWindow.context;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
            ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
            ctx.lineTo(this.width, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(this.width, this.height);
            ctx.lineTo(0, this.height);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        };
```

W3 Schools link: [Game Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_obstacles.asp)

Comment: This 'collision detection' code does a simple bounding box; when different shapes or rotation etc come into play things get a lot more complicated and you'll have to account for that (and write the code) or use a framework that handles this for you. The first option can't be expected to be answered here on StackOverflow, that's a whole subject on itself. The latter just needs some googling for 'game frameworks' or something along those lines.

Comment: @Roblll ok then. Thanks for the help anyways! I'll see what I can find.

Comment: look up separating axis theorem

Comment: A simple hack and quick fix is to design your spaceship to have the same width and height. Ships like the Millenium Falcon form Star Wars is perfect for this. Having unchanging width and height means you don't need to account for rotation.